# PatrickCollins_smart_contract_course_dot_env_file

Tags: hardhat

**HI, I completely forgot the most of the variables here, someone please tell me where to find it. If you have the minute in the video I will appreaciate it too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ**

***.env.example file***

```
GOERLI_RPC_URL='https://alchemy.infura.io/v3/1234567890'
POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL='https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com'
PRIVATE_KEY='abcdefg'
ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL="https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
REPORT_GAS=true
COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY="YOUR_KEY"
AUTO_FUND=true
MNEMONIC="your mnemonic"
ETHERSCAN_API_KEY="Your etherscan API key"
POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY="Your polygonscan API key"
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

1. GOERLI_RPC_URL='https://alchemy.infura.io/v3/1234567890'
   Go alchemy.com register, create an account, create an app choosing goerli as a network
2. POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL='https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com' leave it as it comes.
   3.PRIVATE_KEY='abcdefg' of your metamask or your wallet, select private key from your account 0. (the first that appear)
   4.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL="https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
   Create other app in the ethereum mainnet and put the API ket generated for your app at the end, replacing the "your-api-key"
   5.REPORT_GAS=true leave it as it comes by default.
   6.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY="YOUR_KEY" Go to your coinmarketcap account in the developers API section (https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/v1) that's the link
   7.AUTO_FUND=true leave it as it comes
3. MNEMONIC="your mnemonic" Put in there all the words of your wallet passphrase
   9.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY="Your etherscan API key" Go to etherscan.io create an account and then, create an api key, put it in there.
   10.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY="Your polygonscan API key" Go to polygonscan.com create an account and then, create an api key, put it in there.

Have fun and make an amazing day.